# Смена темы приложения через настройки

Tags: android

Помогите найти ошибку. При запуске загружается тема по умолчанию, а не сохраненная.

```
public class ThemeUtils {
private static int sTheme;
public final static int THEME_LIGHT = 1;
public final static int THEME_DARK = 2;

public static void changeToTheme(Activity activity, int theme) {
    sTheme = theme;
    activity.finish();
    activity.startActivity(new Intent(activity, activity.getClass()));
}

public static void onActivityCreateSetTheme(Activity activity) {
    switch (sTheme) {
        case THEME_LIGHT:
            activity.setTheme(R.style.AppThemeLight);
            break;
        case THEME_DARK:
            activity.setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
            break;
    }

}
```

}

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (CURRENT_THEME == "lightTheme") {
        setTheme(R.style.AppThemeLight);
    } else
        setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
 //ThemeUtils.onActivityCreateSetTheme(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.lightTheme:
            sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor1 = sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor1.putString(CURRENT_THEME, "lightTheme");
            editor1.commit();
            ThemeUtils.changeToTheme(this, ThemeUtils.THEME_LIGHT);
            return true;
        case R.id.darkTheme:
            sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor2 = sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor2.putString(CURRENT_THEME, "darkTheme");
            editor2.commit();
            ThemeUtils.changeToTheme(this, ThemeUtils.THEME_DARK);
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Что если в дебаггере посмотреть? А каким образом ты его сохраняешь?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй вызвать `setTheme` перед `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`

должно сработать.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (CURRENT_THEME == "lightTheme") {
        setTheme(R.style.AppThemeLight);
    } else {
        setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
    }
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
}
```

как то так!
А то получается что ты вызываешь цикл создования view с темой что ты задал в манифесте и после меняешь его.

Comment: только темная тема загружается

Comment: проверь что у тебя хранится в CURRENT_THEME, уверен что не "lightTheme"

Comment: нет. тут весь код. только два значения. зачем база данных

Comment: вы проверили что у вас в  CURRENT_THEME в момент когда он дошел до `if`?

Comment: ты не можешь в программе сохранять значения :\ вот зачем нужна бд или файл с которого программа будет схитывать значения. твоя программа при выходе (онДестрой) все возвращяет в начальный вид а контруктор все строит как было задано. короче тебе надо жизненные циклы изучить, не с того начал ты.

Comment: в CURRENT_THEME "current_theme"

Comment: понятно. спасибо за наводку

Comment: ты прав насчет преференсов прочитай api может что-то нетак делаешь

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81500/discussion-between-sargis-tovmasyan-and-electra).